# Copying references down rows but offsetting 1 column

Tags: excel

In K41:W41, I have references that start at K10 and go through W10. How can I copy this reference set down rows but have the references offset by 1 column for each row down. So, in K42:W42, I would I have L11:X11, and so on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in K41:

```
=OFFSET($K$11,ROW(1:1)-1,COLUMN(A:A)-1+ROW(1:1)-1)
```

Copy over and down.

[image]

Or this non volatile function:

```
=INDEX($K$11:$BD$40,ROW(1:1),COLUMN(A:A)+ROW(1:1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Why do people downvote my question? This has to be one of the douchiest sites on the internet lol.

Comment: @alboman Usually it is expected that the OP show some effort in solving his/her own problem.  Also it is expected that the OP show some test data with expected outcomes.  In General SO is not a request site.  It is a site to help with specific problems.  You just happen to catch me on a break and I found it interesting.  Please mark the answer as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.